# Can not read CD using ATAPI

Tags: assembly, x86, pascal, cd-rom, ata

Here is my code. It fills ATAPI_RAWDATA array with 65535 in decimal. No Error codes. Secondary Error Register Port filled with 0. It does not halt and there is no cpu_triple_fault. When I remove Secondary Master CD device the procedure halts normaly. These loops in code for detecting BSY bit or something else. I tried EJECT procedure in real hardware so there is not any problem on that code but ATAPIREADSECTOR procedure not going fine. Is there any problem on READCD Command or something else?

```
var
READCD:array[0..5] of word($00BE,$0000,$0000,$0000,$0001,$0000);
ATAPI_RAWdata:array[0..1023] of word;
procedure ATAPI_READSECTOR(LBA:Integer;Dev:Byte);
var
i:integer;
x:word;
begin
asm
mov dx,177h
@loop1:
in al,dx
and al,10000000b
jne @loop1
mov dx,177h
@loop2:
in al,dx
and al,01000000b
je @loop2
mov dx,176h
mov al,0A0h
out dx,al
mov dx,3F6h
mov al,00001010b
out dx,al
mov dx,177h
mov al,0a0h
out dx,al
mov cx,0FFFFh
@waitloop:
loopnz @waitloop
mov dx,177h
@loop3:
in al,dx
and al,10000000b
jne @loop3
mov dx,177h
@loop4:
in al,dx
and al,00001000b
je @loop4
end;
for i:=0 to 5 do begin //SEND COMMAND
x:=READCD[i];
outw($170,x);
inb($376);
end;
inb($376);
asm
mov dx,177h
@loop5:
in al,dx
and al,10000000b
jne @loop5
end;
for i:=0 to 1023 do begin //INPUT DATA from DATA REGISTER
atapi_rawdata[i]:=inw($170);
end;
end;
```

My EJECT procedure works fine:

```
var
EJECT_COM:array [0..5] of Word=($001B,$0000,$0002,$0000,$0000,$0000);
procedure EJECT_CD;
var
i:integer;
x:word;
begin
asm
mov dx,177h
@loop1:
in al,dx
and al,10000000b
jne @loop1
mov dx,177h
@loop2:
in al,dx
and al,01000000b
je @loop2
mov dx,176h
mov al,0A0h
out dx,al
mov dx,3F6h
mov al,00001010b
out dx,al
mov dx,177h
mov al,0a0h
out dx,al
mov cx,0FFFFh
@waitloop:
loopnz @waitloop
mov dx,177h
@loop3:
in al,dx
and al,10000000b
jne @loop3
mov dx,177h
@loop4:
in al,dx
and al,00001000b
je @loop4
end;
for i:=0 to 5 do begin
x:=EJECT_COM[i];
outw($170,x);
inb($376);
end;
inb($376);
asm
mov dx,177h
@loop5:
in al,dx
and al,10000000b
jne @loop5
end;
end;
```

Comment: Does that `for` construct generate an unrolled loop...? Wouldn't it be enough to have just a normal loop?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen  It's hard to tell because of its atrocious formatting but the code is written using inline assembly in some variant of Pascal (probably Delphi) so that's just a normal Pascal for loop.

Comment: @RossRidge: Ooh, OK. I thought it was some kind of bizarre macro assembler.

Comment: I generally dont't ask this, usually ignore bizarre questions, but i am interested in why would you want to write code to read a cd in assembly language?

Comment: For my hobby os @barny

Comment: Ross Ridge: Delphi1 maybe for win3.1x.  Anything after that was 32-bit, and this is 16-bit assembler. Most probably it is Turbo Pascal though.

Comment: Probably Turbo Pascal, indeed. Reading ports directly is something you shouldn't do under Windows, not even Windows 3.x. If this is for a hobby OS, then there is very likely no Windows anyway.

Comment: It is FPC. And i solved the problem with correcting command array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SCSI command READ CD $BE not using that structure so use READ 12 $A8 SCSI COMMAND instead of READ CD $BE:

```
READCD:array[0..5] of word($00A8,$0000,$0000,$0000,$0001,$0000);
```